# Why are the values ​of the same parameter in $_REQUEST and $_POST different？

Tags: php, http

When I was developing, I used `print_r()` to print the value of $_REQUEST and $_POST. And I found they are not the same in payload. Compared with other parameters,payload is a urlencoded string.
I tried to find the difference between $_REQUEST and $_POST, only found $_REQUEST include $_POST.

value of post:

```
Array(
[payload] => (!f,΂\)RZ;@:7.6.82B9H
[type] => 1
)
```

value of $_REQUEST

```
Array(
[payload] => (!�f,�΂\�)�R�Z�;@:7.6.82B9H
[type] => 1
)
```

Question:
1.why are $_REQUEST and $_POST different?
2.How can I find the source code of initialization of $_REQUEST？

Update: I wrote the wrong value of payload. I corrected it

the way i send data:
thunder client

the screenshot of parameters:
[image]

detail parameters:

> type:1
> payload:%3D%3D%10%00%18%00%2B%00%28%00%21%90f%2C%9A%CE%82%5C%C0%29%A8R%B3%07Z%F9%3B%40%3A%067.6.82B%019H%00

Comment: $_REQUEST is a combination of Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and Server parameters/variables. In which order they overwrite each other, depends on the configuration - `variables_order`, default is `EGPCS`. So could the value you see in $_REQUEST, be from a different source than the one in $_POST here, in your scenario?

Comment: Also you can use `urldecode(<value of $_REQUEST payload>);` to get the decoded value.

Comment: If you know the data comes in a POST request, use `$_POST`. if you know it comes from a GET request (query string), use `$_GET`. `$_REQUEST` will contain info from multiple different superglobals, and if you're not sure how it's configured in your php.ini (which takes precedence over the other in case there are a name conflict), you can get unexpected results which can lead to hard to find bugs.

Comment: @CBroe Maybe this's the reason.How can I see the configuration **variables_order**.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I know payload comes from $_POST,but in $_POST,but the value of $_POST is not as expected. The value of $_REQUEST is as expected.

Comment: @nice_dev Sorry,I wrote the wrong value of payload. I corrected it

Comment: Can you show us how you actually send the data? It might make it easier if we have a full example we can test with, and see what's going on.

Comment: @M.Eriksson  I use Thunder Client to send data,I updated the specifics to the question.